# Create all combinations of array with keys

Tags: php, arrays

I have got the following array:

```
[
    'Key' => 'HP',
    'OverrideFinanceParameters' => [
        'Term' => 60,
        'Deposit' => 250,
        'DepositType' => 'Amount',
        'AnnualMileage' => 8000
    ]
];
```

I need to add the above to another array for all possible combinations of the following 4 arrays:

```
$products = [ 'HP', 'PCP' ];
$terms = [ 12, 24, 36, 48, 60 ];
$deposit = [ 250, 500, 1000, 3000 ];
$mileages = [ 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000 ];
```

So I would end up with:

```
[
    [
        'Key' => 'HP',
        'OverrideFinanceParameters' => [
            'Term' => 12,
            'Deposit' => 250,
            'DepositType' => 'Amount',
            'AnnualMileage' => 8000
        ]
    ],
    [
        'Key' => 'HP',
        'OverrideFinanceParameters' => [
            'Term' => 24,
            'Deposit' => 250,
            'DepositType' => 'Amount',
            'AnnualMileage' => 8000
        ]
    ],
    [
        'Key' => 'HP',
        'OverrideFinanceParameters' => [
            'Term' => 36,
            'Deposit' => 250,
            'DepositType' => 'Amount',
            'AnnualMileage' => 8000
        ]
    ]
]
```

Comment: and what have you tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically you should loop through all the different values and put them to final array.

```
$resultArray = [];

foreach ($products as $product) {
    foreach ($terms as $term) {
        foreach ($deposit as $depo) {
            foreach ($mileages as $mileage) {
                $resultArray[] = [
                    'Key' => $product,
                    'OverrideFinanceParameters' => [
                        'Term' => $term,
                        'Deposit' => $depo,
                        'DepositType' => 'Amount',
                        'AnnualMileage' => $mileage
                    ]
                ];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought of doing that but didn't think it was too clean, thought there might of been a nicer way.

Comment: I don't think you should consider performance when you have really small arrays and this is simplest way.

Comment: @MartynBall if you considered it why not write it yourself and then ask on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ if there's a better way to do it ?